# How to write Audit methods in Java?

Tags: java, interface, methods, audit, testing

As my java application increases in complexity i want to write audit methods to make sure that i am doing the right thing.

How can i do it in java?
thx

Comment: What do you mean by audit methods?  Assertions?  Logging?  Something else?

Comment: This should be closed as "not a real question".  We have no idea what he really wants to know.

Answer (score 2):

he probably means unit tests

check this to get started: http://junit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps using AspectJ to audit certain method calls?

You can make pointcuts which are like filters and catch when certain methods are called and get information about the parameters. This could be good for auditing.

[Aspect J](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/)